# How to view sqlite database table in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

There is an embedded database provided by Django for small project purpose. 
How can I view the table created in that database?
This command "python manage.py dbshell" isn't working.

```
PS C:\mysite> python manage.py dbshell
CommandError: You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path.
PS C:\mysite>
```

Comment: It's not duplicate. Here I want to know how to view that table of a database of Django embedded database.  Mentioned question is about commands.

Comment: you are on windows?

Comment: yes. Using windows 10

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70805162/virtual-environment-djangos-db-commanderror-you-appear-not-to-have-the-sq

Answer (score 1):

you dont have sqlite3 on your os

use this if you are using ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

for windows 
go to https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

download the zip file install on your system

First, create a new folder e.g., C:\sqlite. Second, extract the content of the file that you downloaded in the previous section to the C:\sqlite folder. You should see the sqlite3.exe is in the C:\sqlite folder. To verify the installation, you perform the following steps:

Append the directory where you installed the sqlite to the system path variable in windows environment variables.